# SSIS Dynamic population of Excel File Name

Tags: excel, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I've written an SSIS package to upload data from an Excel source to a OLE DB Destination - however when I wish to use a ForeachLoop container in order to load data from multiple excel files I am getting an error.  I have followed the tutorial contained in the link below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345182.aspx

All of the configurations are correct apart from the Variable strFileName which needs to be dynamically populated.  As can be seen from the screen shot below my variable remains blank:

[image]

I am unsure how to do this.  Is there an expression or function that can be used to dynamically populate this variable?

Comment: Whats the error and what throws it? Why ask a question and not post the error?

Comment: Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task, Excel Source [36]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
Error: 0xC02020E8 at Data Flow Task, Excel Source [36]: Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
Error: 0xC004706B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want stored fileName dynamically for each one in your folder use the Variable Mappings in your loop like this

[Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTHQ7.png)

And for your loop:

[ForEach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbO1M.png)

Note that your variable is always blank because the field is only updated when you enter in your loop.

Comment: I have those settings as you displayed in the images but I am still getting the following errors:

Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task, Excel Source [36]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
Error: 0xC02020E8 at Data Flow Task, Excel Source [36]: Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
Error: 0xC004706B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Comment: Check your Excel Connection Manager and your DataFlowTask, verify your source (or destination).
If you use a variable for your filename, in the Task property change DelayValidation ='false' to 'true'